# Custom Post type and Custom Field WP_Query

Tags: custom-post-types, wp-query, custom-field, advanced-custom-fields

I am developing a site for a client who is a Youth Football (Soccer) Club, with lots of different Teams depending on the abilities and ages of the children. I have added in a Custom Post Type called Match Reports so that the Managers of each Team can login and write posts for their latest matches their teams were involved in.

I also have a News section using the standard Posts part of WP. I have written a Shortcode which will display the News on the Homepage. What I want to be able to do is enable a system where one of the Match Reports can be added to the Homepage by selecting an option, using the Advanced Custom Fields plugin - it is a two-option radio button form, with true/false values - Show on Homepage? Yes/No.

In my News shortcode, I have added the Match Reports Custom Post Type in, which works perfectly, but I am not sure how to only show the Reports with the "Show on Homepage - Yes" radio button selected. Here are my Query Parameters:

```
$queryArgs = array(
    "post_type" => array( "post", "match-report" ),
    "meta_key" => "show_in_news",
    "meta_value" => "true"
);
```

The problem with this is that because the standard Posts do not have the Custom Field in, only the Match Reports show up, and if I remove the Custom Field queries, it will show all the Match Reports together with the Posts. I need it to only show the Match Reports with `show_in_news` (my Custom Field with radio buttons, created with Advanced Custom Fields, with a value of a `true`, together with all of the Posts.

Can anyone help me out? Thanks very much if so :)

Comment: @PieterGoosen thanks for the comment - if possible, could you give me an example? I'm not exactly sure how I'd go about doing that. Thanks :)

Comment: I will try to look into this a bit later. Posting from my phone, so it is a bit difficult.

Comment: Ah, great, got it solved. Enjoy :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently your meta query is exclusive and you need to make it inclusive. For example, you can save **always** the meta field `show_in_news` for match-report custom post type, even when the value is `false`. Then, you can include posts if custom `show_in_news` doesn't exist (standard posts) or if it exists and it is `"true"` for custom post type:

```
$queryArgs = array(
    "post_type" => array( "post", "match-report" ),
    "meta_query" => array( 
        "relation" => "OR",
        array(
            "key" => "show_in_news",
            "compare" => "NOT EXISTS",
        ),
        array(
            "key"   => "show_in_news",
            "value" => "true",
        ),
    ),
);
```

This should do the job.